# WindowLeaked error while showing PopupWindow

Tags: popupwindow

I know this question is asked many times on stackoverflow but I am unable to find the answer that can fix my problem.

Here is the code that I have called from onPause() function of my Activity.

```
`

`protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        new DialogueTask().execute(this);   
        }
```

And implementation of Dialogue class task is

```
class DialogueTask extends AsyncTask<Activity, Void, PopupWindow> {
    private View layout;

    @Override
    protected PopupWindow doInBackground(Activity... activities) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activities[0]
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,
                (ViewGroup) activities[0].findViewById(R.id.popup_id));
        PopupWindow pw;
        pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 100, 100, true);
        return pw;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PopupWindow pw) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
```

This is the popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Sure you want to Quit?" >
    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

While clicking back button then onPause() is called and it gives WindowLeaked exception. I think, I have taken care that popup window is shown in UI thread by implementing AsyncTask. Then where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Popup window activity is opened from the main activity, and you are exiting from the main activity without dismissing the pop-up window activity..
pw.dismiss() after pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0) will solve the problem

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(PopupWindow pw) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    pw.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: on adding pw.dismiss() the popup will not appear on the screen. With the pause of activity, popup will also get disappeared.